# How do I have two different chapter numberings going on at once?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, counters, cjk

I am writing a strange textbook that needs each chapter in Chinese and then one English, all in the same book.  I need there to be two chapter ones, two chapter twos, etc. The [zhnumber package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/zhnumber?lang=en) has all the numberings I need (cp. `\arabic`), but how I make something like `\chapter` and `\zhchapter`?  I need the counters to run separately, and all appear in the TOC (in the right font).  I can make `titlesec` create chapter headings that I want, but how I can I make two different ones, depending on the kind of chapter?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. It would help to see what you have already done, especially as the answer to your question depends upon the class file that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.

In the example i used english and french but it is same. The idea is

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%
\ifodd\c@chapter
\@roman\numexpr(\c@chapter+1)/2\relax%  %roman just for the example
\else 
\@arabic\numexpr\c@chapter/2\relax%     %arabic just for the example
\fi}
\makeatother
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%
\ifodd\c@chapter
\@roman\numexpr(\c@chapter+1)/2\relax%
\else 
\@arabic\numexpr\c@chapter/2\relax%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo1}
\section{Bar1}
\subsection{Baz1}
\selectlanguage{french}
\chapter{French foo1}
\section{French bla1}
\subsection{French baz1}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{Foo2}
\section{Bar2}
\subsection{Baz2}
\selectlanguage{french}
\chapter{French foo2}
\section{French bla2}
\subsection{French baz2}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{Foo3}
\section{Bar3}
\subsection{Baz3}
\selectlanguage{french}
\chapter{French foo3}
\section{French bla3}
\subsection{French baz3}
\selectlanguage{english}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to format the chapters differently (using `titlesec`)?  I need different fonts for Chinese and English (I'm using XeLaTeX).

Comment: you can use `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\ifodd\value{chapter} stuff\else another stuff\fi}{ ifodd\value{chapter}...\else ...\fi}...` it works within all arguments